# Can't update cached Ebean Entity

Tags: java, caching, ebean, playframework-2.5

We have a play-application (2.5.10) using the ebean sbt-play-ebean plugin in version 3.1.0 which provides ebean 8.2.3

We have Model which (simplyfied) looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class User extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Version
  public Timestamp lastUpdated;

  public String name;
}
```

In a Controller we have the following lines:

```
User user = User.find.setUseCache(true).setId(id).findUnique();
user.name = "something";
user.update();
```

After executing this, the field "name" is not updated in the database. The only field that's changed is "lastUpdated".
With query logging, we can see that even the update query only contains the "lastUpdated" field to updated, but not the "name".

Now if we change the line which selects the User to

```
User user = User.find.setUseCache(false).setId(id).findUnique();
```

it works.

So only if we don't use the L2 Cache, we can perfrom updates. In an older ebean Version (bundled with play 2.3) this worked fine.

Using no L2 Cache is not an option, because we have this problem on much more complex constellations which would rely on caching.

Is there something we are missing to update beans loaded from the cache?

Comment: Have you tried `markAsDirty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the few people who will also stumble upon this issue: it's a bug in ebean.

Here's more information and the steps to reproduce

https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/pull/1039

https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/1040

Hopefully, this will get fixed in the future, so we can manually update to the latest ebean version.

**edit**: the issue has been solve in the following release: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-ebean_2.11/3.2.0